# When using python 3.x, how do I take outputs from a "for" command and add them to a list or string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would I take the results from the following code and assign a variable to it?

```
for I in word: print (I + 117)
```

For example, if the results came out to be `100,101,102,103` how would I get a variable set to `"100,101,102,103"` without manually entering every number into a variable. Also, I know that it says "your encrypted string is" and I know that that's not really encrypted, but I just got into this so I was just playing around.

```
word = eval(input("What would you like to say"))

print (word)

encrypt = 117

print ("Your encrypted string is:")

for I in word:

print (I + 117)
```

assuming I have ASCII codes set to their appropriate values

Thanks to many people (most notably yukashima huksay and ZYYYY) I have my final code here:

```
word = eval(input("What would you like to say"))
print (word)
changedword = (', '.join(str(I + 15) for I in word))
print ("Your encrypted string is:" + changedword)
```

Assuming all ASCII codes set as variables.

Comment: Post all code here directly as text. Posting text as an image just needlessly complicates matters.

Comment: BTW, you can convert integers to and from ASCII using `ord()` and `chr()`. For example `chr(97)` is `'a'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this:

```
a = ','.join([x for x in word])
```

Please note that you can use any string instead of `','` for example `', '` or `'\n'` or basically whatever you can store in a string.

You can also put a function of x instead like `[foo(x) for x in word]` or `(2*x + 1)`

And finally you can also use in-line if/else statements like:

```
[foo(x) if x>1 else bar(x) for x in word]
```

And also:

```
[foo(x) for x in word if x is not None]
```

The error you are getting is because you are adding a number to a character perhaps what you want to do is:

```
word = 'mokhlesim'
shift = 117
print(','.join([chr(ord(x)+shift) for x in word]))
```

result: è,Ö,á,Ö,â

Comment: @Dom please let me know if there is anything more you need about it.

Comment: trying to add that in didn't work because it's not originally a string, it's just a list of numbers in a separate variable. sorry for the late reply I was trying everything out. Also, thanks for the very fast reply, I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: at least I think that's the problem like I said I'm very new to this.when trying to run it tells me  "TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found"

Comment: That is because you are adding a number to a character.

Comment: keep getting TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found

Comment: Did you exactly copy paste the three line code I posted here? By the way as ZYYYY pointed out you don't need that eval.

Comment: I just ended up figuring it out, almost exactly as you said but with a few minor changes.    "(obv I can be x or whatever) print(', '.join(str(I + 15) for I in word))" this will print it but swapping print with whatever var works.

Answer (score -1):

`str.join(iterable)` would give you what you want.

I don't think `eval()` is a good practice here. `word = input("somethin")` is enough for python3.

Also you may want to know about [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) which makes code more concise.

`eval(exp)` is to use to parse and evaluate `exp` as a python expression. For example

```
x = 1
a = eval("x + 1")
print(a)
#should print 2
```

I think you may want something like

```
word = input("give me something\n")
a = ','.join([chr(ord(c) + 117) for c in word])
print(a)
#if i type in here, it should print "Ý,Ú,ç,Ú"
```

Comment: I would be converting to and from ASCII code, so I would have to have eval in order to get the var recognized as variables, correct?